# How to get condition based data between nested relationsiop hasmany in laravel

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

Enrollments model:

```
public function schedule_weeks() {
        return $this->hasMany( Enrollment_weeks::class, 'enrollment_id', 'id' )->where( 'enrollment_weeks.status', 'ACTIVE' );
    }
```

Enrollment_weeks Models:

```
public function week_classes() {
        return $this->hasOne( Enrollment_week_classes::class, 'enrollment_week_id', 'id' );
    }
```

if i give without where condition i got proper nested data

```
$enrol_info = Enrollments::with( [ 'student_info', 'schedule_weeks.week_classes'  ] )->find( $id );
```

if i give where condtion i got error

```
$enrol_info  = Enrollments::with( [ 'student_info', 'schedule_weeks.week_classes' => function( $query ) {
                                                $query->where( 'enrollment_weeks.order', '>=', '1' );
                                                $query->where( 'enrollment_weeks.order', '<=', '3' );
                                            }  ] )

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'enrollment_weeks.order' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `enrollment_week_classes` where `enrollment_week_classes`.`enrollment_week_id` in (52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60) and `enrollment_weeks`.`order` >= 1 and `enrollment_weeks`.`order` <= 3)
```

but if i gave like this

```
$enrol_info  = Enrollments::with( [ 'student_info', 'schedule_weeks' => function( $query ) {
                                                $query->where( 'enrollment_weeks.order', '>=', '1' );
                                                $query->where( 'enrollment_weeks.order', '<=', '3' );
                                            }  ] )
```

i got data without nested weekclass data

pls help me to get nested weekclass data with condition

Answer (score 0):

```
$enrol_info = Enrollments::with([
    'student_info',
    'schedule_weeks' => function ($query) {
        // add the nested relation here
        $query->with('week_classes');

        $query->where('enrollment_weeks.order', '>=', '1');
        $query->where('enrollment_weeks.order', '<=', '3');
    },
]);
```

this is the exact answer will help someone liked me